# Bug textarea com padding no Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

O `padding-bottom` em um `<textarea>`, funciona normalmente no *Google Chrome* e em outros navegadores ao rolar o scrollbar, mas no Firefox o espaçamento sempre fica "fixo" e os textos aparecem cortados.

Diferença no Opera (baseado em Chromium) e Firefox:

[image: Diferença entre Opera e Firefox]

O problema só ocorre no Firefox, outros navegadores funcionam normalmente. O bug está listado no Bugzilla https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1099204

Gostaria de saber se é possível contornar isto? Por exemplo trocar o padding por outra coisa.

**Exemplo do problema:**

```css
.foo {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    padding-bottom: 150px;  
}
```

```html
<textarea class="foo">
Bacon ipsum dolor amet ground round cow chuck tail t-bone ribeye jowl
meatloaf ham turducken. Cupim boudin frankfurter pig, hamburger drumstick
beef ribs kielbasa pastrami tri-tip. Beef ribs turkey porchetta, pastrami ham
meatball sirloin frankfurter venison. Pastrami brisket chicken shoulder,
landjaeger chuck burgdoggen alcatra. Tongue shank boudin jerky chicken capicola
pork loin kevin burgdoggen tri-tip. Chicken meatloaf spare ribs bresaola,
bacon porchetta leberkas drumstick sausage.
</textarea>
```

Comment: Estou fechando a pergunta pois o bug foi corrigido ([aparentemente em 2021](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1456052)), infelizmente tivemos que esperar [6 anos](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1099204) para corrigirem o bug.

Answer (score 9):

Realmente, o `padding` está bem *bugado* no Firefox. Certa vez eu também tive um problema, mas abri um chamado no [Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/) e foi bem rápido a correção.

Se for tão importante utilizar o `padding`,  você pode simular o `textarea` utilizando um `contenteditable` do HTML5, e pelo que eu tenho visto, ele está com suporte em todos os navegadores (confira sua compatibilidade [aqui](http://caniuse.com/#search=contenteditable)).

Sendo assim, faça:

```css
.post {
  background-color: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid #e1e8ed;
  padding-bottom: 150px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="post" contenteditable="true">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla placerat
   tortor turpis, ut commodo nunc pretium tincidunt. Fusce tempus sed arcu 
   sed vestibulum. Phasellus pulvinar dui eu urna laoreet condimentum. 
   Phasellus vel mi auctor, convallis felis vitae, efficitur ipsum. Duis 
   eget lacus sed velit lacinia pharetra.
</div>
```

Comment: Excelente sugestão, vou tentar implementar, todavia pode ser uma dor de cabeça para quem necessita de textos simples, teria que colocar um filtro nos eventos input e paste. Mas é uma ótima ideia ainda, se nada mais aparecer vou escolher tua sugestão :)

Comment: Infelizmente no caso do bug levaram 6 anos para corrigir (ficou separado em 2 bugreports, como [comentei](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/147840/bug-textarea-com-padding-no-firefox#comment995494_147840)), de qualquer forma obrigado pela sugestão na época.